# Scala Spray Security Issue or Scan?

Tags: scala, security, http, spray

I've been following my spray server logs and this has started to show up:

```
DEBUG HttpServerConnection - Dispatching GET request to http://37.28.156.211/sprawdza.php to handler Actor[akka://Permissions/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/1820#857492247]
DEBUG HttpServerConnection - Dispatching GET request to http://www.qunar.com/ to handler Actor[akka://Permissions/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/1927#690613265]
```

I'm not able to understand these. How come I get a request that is not targeted at my server? Is it some kind of scan to see if I act as a proxy and forward the request?
Comments are very welcome!

Comment: Probably what is being logged there is the HTTP host field which the client provides. Since it seems it doesn't match your domain or IP, it is likely some malevolent software and you're best to drop the request (don't even reply).

Comment: Yes, spray uses the host header and the relative target of the request to build an absolute request which is why you see those lines.